# AVD camera configurations and key mappings

Tags: android-sdk, screencast, virtualization, avd-manager

AVD: Android Virtual Device

#### Currently available AVD camera configurations are...

**Front Camera:** 
None - no camera installed for AVD
Emulated - use a simpulated camera
Device - use host computer webcam or built-in camera
**Back Camera:** 
None - no camera installed for AVD
VirtualScene - use a virtual camera in simulated environment
Emulated - use a simulated camera
Device - use host computer webcam or built-in

### I want an option... say...

HostSystemScreen - capture your host system's screen
Which simply means that the AVD camera can act as my desktop screen-recorder. For an app that scans a QR code from the web-browser for some verification. installed in AVD, its will be super helpful if its camera opens to view my desktop.
How can I do it?

---

System Info
OS: Elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Kernel: 5.1.0-generic
CPU: i5-2410M
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M
RAM: 12GB

AVD:
API: 28 Pie
Google Play Image
Pixel XL 2
CPU: x86
*Couldn't find the tag `android-studio`*

## Edit

I've got an idea to link up AVD to any native [screen-recorder](https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr), but I really need help on it.

[image: Here's what I need]
*I'm not perfect in playing with picture editors*

### One more thing...

Can I map the **HOME** & **END** button of my *physical keyboard* as **start** and **end** of the line being typed in the AVD?

> Currently the HOME key navigates to the home screen, and the END key does nothing particular.

Comment: Not directly - you have to do it manually: Create a screen-shot, save it to a file and then let the emulator use it as picture source.

Comment: I hope you have seen the [same question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131927) 

But by then the QR code will expire.

Comment: That you don't get much replies makes me no wonder. Your question is not very clear. The only real info is in the title which is quite bad. reformulate it and write some sentences describing what and why.

Comment: @Robert, I made some real changes to the question, I'm open to further improvement, thanks to all who respond in advance.

Comment: In the end your question is very similar to this one: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176977/feed-an-image-to-genymotion-camera